# UML about packages

Tags: uml, staruml

Ok, I'm preparing an exam and I need the answer to this question, that I couldn't find in the book. Hope that you can help me.

What is needed for the `A package` to access the `B package`? (1 of the 2 answers is the right one)

1. `A` will import `B` and `B` will export the elements establishing the visibilities that fit better
2. We just need an `<<import>>` from `A` to `B`

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need an `<<import>>` as stated in the UML spec on p. 32 in an example:

> In Figure 7.9, a number of PackageImports are shown. The public members of Types are imported into ShoppingCart and then further imported into WebShop. However, the members of Auxiliary are only privately imported by ShoppingCart and cannot be referenced using unqualified names from WebShop.

[image]